# Custom Skill does not execute async function that delivers Promise

Tags: node.js, async-await, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am programming my own Alexa Skill using node.js and the lambda server. My Alexa Custom skill gets a zip file from a website and uploads the zip file to google drive. 
For this I use an asynchronous function, that awaits a Promise object from the getFile() function.
The code works local, so I think the lambda function can't handle my async call.

I implemented it without async and await, but then I get the error message:

```
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "chunk" argument must be one of type string or Buffer. Received type object.


function getFile() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

   //from here on nothing is executed anymore

    request(
      {
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://start.spring.io/starter.zip",
        encoding: null // <- this one is important !
      },
      function(error, response, body) {
        if (error && response.statusCode != 200) {
          reject(error);
          return;
        }
        resolve(body);
      }
    );
  });
}

 async function uploadFile(auth) { 

  const stream = require("stream"); 

  const buffer = await getFile(); // from here on nothing is executed anymore


  const bs = new stream.PassThrough();
  bs.end(buffer);

  const drive = google.drive({ version: "v3", auth });
  var fileMetadata = {
    name: "demo.zip"
  };
  var media = {
    mimeType: "application/zip",
    body: bs // Modified
  };
  drive.files.create(
    {

      resource: fileMetadata,
      media: media,
      fields: "id"
    },
    function(err, res) {
      if (err) {
        // Handle error
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log("File Id: ", res.data.id);
      }
    }
  );
}`
```

Comment: Not really an Alexa question. But do you have any errors logged? If you're deploying to Lambda, check your CloudWatch logs. Also, try wrapping `const buffer = await getFile()` in a try/catch, then log any error in the catch - might help you some more.

Answer (score 0):

Also, make sure that your lambda runtime is node 8.10. Async / Await is not supported in node 4.3

[Function Code Runtime](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8jUa.png)